# html tag style issue

Tags: html, css

I am trying to customize an input field with an inline style yet it is not working

Here is my attempt

```html
<div class="row vh-md-100">
  <div class="col-md-7 my-md-auto text-center text-md-left">
    <h1 class="display-3 text-white font-weight-bold">Div</h1>
    <p class="lead text-light my-4">Div</p>
    <input style="width:1;" width="1" placeholder="What is your best email">
    <a href="#signup" class="btn btn-primary page-scroll">send</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

I was expecting for the input width to change yet that is not happening. What am I missing

Comment: Try style="width:1px;"

Comment: You need to assign the unit for the style, like `width: 1px`

Answer (score 2):

Because you did not specify a unit for it.

You wrote `width: 1`, but `1` what? It can be `cm`, `px`, `em` and many thing else. [You need to specify it](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/length).

If you read the documentation in the link, you will see the list of all units and the only number you can use without a unit is `0`.

```html
<div class="row vh-md-100">
  <div class="col-md-7 my-md-auto text-center text-md-left">
    <h1 class="display-3 text-white font-weight-bold">Div</h1>
    <p class="lead text-light my-4">Div</p>
    <input  style="width:1px;" width="1" placeholder="What is your best email">
    <a href="#signup" class="btn btn-primary page-scroll">send</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

it should have a unit.
try 1px.
see below

```html
<div class="row vh-md-100">
                    <div class="col-md-7 my-md-auto text-center text-md-left">
                        <h1 class="display-3 text-white font-weight-bold">Div</h1>
                        <p class="lead text-light my-4">Div</p>
                        <input  style="width:1px;" placeholder="What is your best email">
                        <a href="#signup" class="btn btn-primary page-scroll">send</a>
                    </div>
                </div>
```